# How to load view in a view CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller method `view()`

```
function view() {
    $data['myClass'] = $this;
    $query = $this->db->query("Select * from news");
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach($query->result() as $row) {
            $data['news'][] = $row;
        }
    }

    $this->load->view('news_view', $data);
}
```

View

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll"  direction="left">
    <?php
    $myClass->method('view');
    /*echo "<pre>";
    die(print_r($data, TRUE));*/

    foreach($news as $news) { ?>
        <p id="marque"><?php echo $news->description; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
</marquee>
```

My default controller is home and I want to load this view in my home view
but they give me error of undefined foreach arguments
but when I call the controller function view then it is ok 
and my question is that how can I load this view in home view

I am looking for CakePHP equivalent of [`requestaction()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::requestAction).

Comment: Check your `query()`, possible it returns `NULL`.

Comment: very wrong. Are you following the documentation at all?

Comment: first of all, any interaction with your database should be in a model method, not a controller

Comment: what is this `$myClass->method('view');` suppose to do in your code?

Comment: @Muhammad you need to follow up

Answer (score 0):

You need to break it down and separate your code into MVC. Try this:

Controller:

```
function controller_method() {
    $this->load->model("model_name");
    $data['news'] = $this->model_name->model_method();
    $this->load->view('news_view', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
function model_method() {
    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->from("news");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

View:

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();" scrollamount="5" behavior="scroll"  direction="left">
    <?php foreach ($news as $new) { ?>
        <p id="marque"><?= $new->description; ?></p>
    <?php } ?>
</marquee>
```